# What does AQE stand for?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have seen the acronym AQE in mathematics books in relation to the characteristic equation used in solving second-order homogeneous ordinary differential equation. Although I am not sure what the acronym stands for and I haven't found anywhere on the internet or in the books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen it before, but Google turns up "auxiliary quadratic equation".

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_%28calculus%29), "auxiliary equation" is synonymous with "characteristic equation".

According to this, an "auxiliary quadratic equation" is a characteristic equation of degree two.

(I dislike this acronym, as "q" is the first letter of "quartic" and "quintic" as well.)

Comment: This certainly makes sense, as the characteristic equation of a second-order differential equation is quadratic.

Comment: Yeah, gotta wait a couple of minutes though :D